# how to solve vulnerabilities like Regular Expression Denial of Service?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

When i run my react project i get this following vulnerabilities:

[image]

How can i fix this problem? 
And can anyone please explain me what this actually is warning me about?
Do i need to update `babel-cli`?

I have tried to install `braces@2.3.0` to see if this warning get away, but nothing changes when i install it.

My `package.json` file:

`{
  "name": "Recordshop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "babel-node src-gen/config/startMessage.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src-gen lint:watch",
    "open:src-gen": "babel-node src-gen/config/server.dev.js",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* src-gen src-gen/config",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "clean-prod": "npm run remove-prod && mkdirp prod/app",
    "remove-prod": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./prod",
    "build:html": "babel-node src-gen/config/buildHTML.js",
    "prebuild": "npm-run-all clean-prod lint build:html",
    "build": "babel-node src-gen/config/build.js",
    "postbuild": "babel-node src-gen/config/server.prod.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "reduce-reducers": "^0.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.11",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.8.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "open": "^6.3.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-combine-loaders": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.5",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"
  }
}`

Thank you for all help!

Answer (score 0):

I got same error. And it was the babel-core error. Try update babel-core using `yarn add --dev babel-jest babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0 @babel/core regenerator-runtime`